# FFMPEG windows 10, how to find multimedia file duration command

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

```
D:/Projects/wamp/bin/ffmpeg.exe -y -i D:/Projects/ffmpeg/test.mp4 -f -t
```

This is my command to find mp4 file time duration but giving error in coomand line is "At least one output file must be specified"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffprobe file.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0
```

This will show the output in seconds. Add `-sexagesimal` for output in `HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm`

Comment: Thank you @Mulvya. it's working for me. i appreciate you.